# Key not generated in default,how do I connect without a password?

Tags: ssh, password

I generated my key into a directory "~/test/keys" then I copied it to my server but if I use ssh user@host the password is still required.How do I connect to it withiut a password in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't store your key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (or one of the other default locations - see `man ssh`), you have to tell ssh where your private key is: `ssh -i ~/test/keys`